# Making R to identify what is data.frame and what is a column in `...` arguments

Tags: r

Is it possible to have a function only with the `...` arguments, yet making R to identify what is data.frame and what is a column no matter the order one passes them to a function? For instance, instead of using: `mean(data$column)` I'd like something like `mean(...)`, where `...` would be either `(data, column)` or `(column, data)`.

I thought that maybe `eval` could work, but still parked. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

```
f <- function(...)
{
  args <- list(...)
  x <-eval(substitute(...), ..., parent.frame())
mean(x)
}

f(women, height)

f(height, women)
```

Comment: You can't take the mean of a data frame, and it is best practice to use named arguments in `...`. Plus this doesn't really make much sense

Comment: You're trying to make a (pretty crazy) non-standard evaluating function. I'd recommend reading [Advanced R: Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) and using the `lazyeval` package. (Well, really I'd recommend **not** doing this, but if you're stubborn...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
f <- function(...)
{
  a <- as.list(match.call())
  stopifnot(length(a) == 3L)
  x <- a[[2]]
  y <- a[[3]]
  x <- as.character(x)
  y <- as.character(y)
  tryCatch(get(x, get(y)), 
           error = function(e) tryCatch(get(y, get(x)), 
                                        error = function(e) {
                                          message("no deal")
                                          NULL
                                        }
                                        )
           )
}

f(height, women)
#[1] 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
f(women, height)
#[1] 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
f(women, age)
#no deal
#NULL
f(men, height)
#no deal
#NULL
```

Obviously, there are dragons hiding and you shouldn't use this in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Fun :)

```
set.seed( 1 )
women <- data.frame( height = rnorm( 100, 1.70, 0.1 ) )

f <- function(...){
     args <-as.list( match.call( ) )

     cmnd_a <- paste0("a <- try(class(",args[[ 2 ]],"), silent = TRUE)" )
     a <- eval( parse( text = cmnd_a ) )

     if( a == "data.frame" ){
           cmnd <- paste0("mean(",args[[2]],"$",args[[3]],")")
     }else{
           cmnd <- paste0("mean(",args[[3]],"$",args[[2]],")")}

     eval( parse( text = cmnd ) )

}

> 
> f(height, women)
[1] 1.710889
> 
> f(women, height)
[1] 1.710889
```

Comment: `eval(parse(...))` isn't fun, but seriously ugly business. See [fortune](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf) 106.